# How to call a function using yes or no input

Tags: loops, switch-statement, return-value, function-call

I want to write a C program which could ask the user to enter yes or no to continue subsequent function.
If yes it should call a function,  if no it should return to 0.

I have done until here so far

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
  {

  char y, n, Y, N, ans;
  printf("Would you like to continue ?:\t");
  scanf("%c",&ans);


  switch (ans)
  {
  case 'y':
    {
       void convert();
       return ;
    }
  break;

  default:
    {
        return (0);
    }
  break;
  return 0;
    }

  }


  void convert (){

    printf("hello");


   }
```

what should i do to call function named convert?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback guyss.
And here  i got my answer with your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

char y, n, Y, N, ans;
printf("Would you like to continue ?:\t");
scanf("%c",&ans);


switch (ans)
{
case 'y':
case 'Y':

       convert();


break;


case 'N':
case 'n':

       return(0);


break;


default:
    {
        return (0);
    }

break;
return 0;
}}




void convert (){

    printf("Hello");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone i have given a task to convert an amount in Ringgit Malaysia to its equivalent value in USD.

And I want to write a C program which could ask the user to enter yes or no to continue subsequent function.

As shown below i have done my coding

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

char y, n, Y, N, ans;
printf("\nWould you like to continue ?:\t");
scanf("%c",&ans);


switch (ans)
{
case 'y':
case 'Y':

       convert();


break;


case 'N':
case 'n':

       return(0);


break;


default:
    {
        return (0);
    }

break;
return 0;
}

while (ans==y || ans==Y);
return main();










}




int convert (){

    float ia,ca;

    printf("\nEnter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM ");
    scanf("%f",&ia);

    ca=ia/3.30;

    printf("\nRM %.2f is equals to USD %.2f\n\n\n",ia,ca);

 return main();

}
```

but my output is shown as below

```
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30


Would you like to continue ? : 
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : 
Would you like to continue ? : n
```

My question is why the question repeat twice?

By the way the output should be like this

```
Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : y
Enter amount in Ringgit Malaysia : RM 100
RM 100.00 is equals to USD 30.30

Would you like to continue ? : n
```